# How to set regular expression for a date time field

Tags: regex

I want my text box to accept only yyyy or yy.

I added the regular expression as `^(yyyy|yy)`. It works as expected. 
Additionally I need to add MM as optional. so I modified my regular expression as `^(yyyy|yy)?(MM)`. This is also working as expected.

Now I need to add any non-alphabetic character between year and month. So I modified by regular expression as `^(yyyy|yy)?(w)?(MM)`. This was not working as expected.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. Try to solve the problem yourself first, then include your attempt in your question if you get stuck. Check out the help center for more information about what is considered on-topic for this site, and how to ask a good question.

Comment: To make a text box to accept only yyyy or yy. I added the regular expression as ^(yyyy|yy). It is working as expected. Additionally i need to add MM as optional. so i modified by regular expression as ^(yyyy|yy)?(MM). This is also working as expected. Now i need to add any non-alphabetic character between year and month. So i modified by regular expression as ^(yyyy|yy)?(w)?(MM). This was not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This regex could help you: `/^(Y{2}|Y{4})(\WMM)?$/g`

```js
const regexp = /^(Y{2}|Y{4})(\WMM)?$/g;

const val1 = "YYYY MM";
const val2 = "YY/MM";
const val3 = "YYYYY MM";

console.log(val1, regexp.test(val1))
console.log(val2, regexp.test(val2))
console.log(val3, regexp.test(val3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In my case i wont enter the date in the textbox, Instead I will enter YYYY MM or YYYY/MM or YY MM or YY/MM. Of which MM is optional.